# How can I divide a datatable between 2 listboxes in random order

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table with names and I want to put half of the names in one listbox and the other half in a different listbox in random order. This is what I have now:

```
private void ScheduleMaking()
{
    Schema schema = new Schema();
    schema.SchemaLoading();

    lsbFirstRow.DataSource = schema.dt;
    lsbFirstRow.DisplayMember = "name";

    string[] deelnemersArray = new string[schema.dt.Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < schema.dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        deelnemersArray[i] = schema.dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number = rnd.Next(1, schema.dt.Rows.Count);
        lsbSecondRow.Items.Add(deelnemersArray);
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should declare `Random rnd = new Random();` only once, outside of your loop. When you declare `Random` it uses, broadly, the time as a seed for random numbers so if you are constantly creating a new one in a loop you'll end up with very similar seeds and therefore it won't be very random throughout the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a random way without returning half your list.

```
int[] randomlyDrawnNumbers = new int[deelnemersArray.Count()];
List<string> NewStringList = new List<string>();
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < deelnemersArray.Count()/2; i++)
{
    int number;
    while (true)
    {
        number = r.Next(0, deelnemersArray.Count());
        if (randomlyDrawnNumbers[number]==0)
        {
            randomlyDrawnNumbers[number] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    NewStringList.Add(deelnemersArray[number]);
}
```